# Spring framework - Custom event handling

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In the below code,

```
package com.ca.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware;

public class MyEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware{

    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }

    public void publish() {
        System.out.println("MyEventPublisher.publish() invoked ... ");
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new MyEvent(this));
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ca.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

public class MyEvent extends ApplicationEvent{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.ca.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

public class MyEventListener implements ApplicationListener<MyEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(MyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("MyEventListener.onApplicationEvent() invoked: " + 
                                e.getSource().getClass().getName());        
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.ca.spring;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringBeans.xml"); 
        ((MyEventPublisher)context.getBean("myEventPublisher")).publish();
        context.close();
    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--  Springbeans.xml  -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="myEventPublisher" class="com.ca.spring.MyEventPublisher"/>
    <bean id="myEventListener" class="com.ca.spring.MyEventListener"/>
</beans>
```

---

1) Which object does Spring framework inject to `setApplicationEventPublisher()`? Because there is no dependency mentioned for `myEventPublisher` bean in xml

2) How does  Spring framework decide to inject that specific object?

Comment: What does the javadoc of ApplicationEventPublisherAware say?

Comment: Set the ApplicationEventPublisher that this object runs in. parameter -
 applicationEventPublisher - event publisher to be used by this object

Comment: Interface to be implemented by any object that wishes to be notified of the ApplicationEventPublisher (**typically the ApplicationContext**) that it runs in. (emphasis mine).

Comment: Does MyEventPublisher instance  get passed?

Comment: passed to what? MyEventPublisher is not an instance of ApplicationEventPublisher And injecting MyEventPublisher into MyEventPublisher wouldn't make much sense, would it? What is passed, as the javadoc and my previous comment indicate, is the ApplicationContext, which does implement ApplicationEventPublisher.

Comment: @JBNizet ApplicationContext is the container itself. Why to pass a container?

Comment: Because the container is also the event publisher in Spring.

Comment: @JBNizet But how does IOC container know that, it has to inject ApplicationContext container object. Does container decide to inject ApplicationContext container object because MyEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware?

Comment: Yes. Any bean implementing that interface signals the container that is wishes to be injected with the ApplicationEventPublisher. Again, the javadoc tells it: *Interface to be implemented by any object that wishes to be notified of the ApplicationEventPublisher*.

Comment: @JBNizet Is this considered auto wiring?

Comment: Not really. Autowiring is when you don't declare the dependencies to other beans anywhere (they were typically declared in XML before autowiring existed) and just annotate fields/setters/constructor with Autowired (or Inject) to let the container discover and inject the dependencies.